# How to call a stored procedure in Magento?

Tags: magento, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure, called "myprocedure". How can I call it from Magento?

I tried:

```
$resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
$writeConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_write');
$query = 'CALL myprocedure()';
$results = $writeConnection ->fetchAll($query);
var_dump($results);
```

This gives me a PDO error, why?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$writeConnection->exec(); could help you